# Python/Pandas - Read csv file with tab as delimter is not working as desired

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have a tab seperated csv file like below:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j

    k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

And, I'm reading it to a dataframe with the below code

```
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Delete/input1.csv',encoding='ANSI', delimiter='\t', header=0)
```

When I execute the above code I'm getting output like this image -> 
[what_I_got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9pyz.jpg)

But, I'm expecting like this -> [desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60cRs.jpg)

I tried many ways to split the column but it's not working.Could you help me with a solution please?

Comment: It seems separator is `,` try remove `delimiter='\t',`, because default separator is `,`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @jezrael

Comment: For anyone who actually has this issue (since the question was inaccurate in its assertions): if you're using double-quotes a la `delimiter="\t"`, you're likely passing the delimiter as a literal `t` - try double-escaping it with `delimiter="\\t"` to actually get a tab character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need remove `delimiter='\t'` - separator is `,`.

It working because default separator is `,`, also is possible remove `header=0` because if not parmeter `names` by default `header=0`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/Delete/input1.csv',encoding='ANSI')
```