# I want to read CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data set is like that 
`team1team2seasondatecompetitionmatch_numberGroundcity`

I want output like that:

```
team1   team2   season  date    competition match_number    Ground  city
```

```
import pandas as pd df=pd.read_csv("C://Users//C_v//Desktop//test.csv",delimiter=",")
df
```

It gives me output like that:

```
team1team2seasondatecompetitionmatch_numberGroundcity
0   Pakistan\tIndia\t2006\t2/11/2006\tIndia in Pak...   NaN
1   Pakistan\tIndia\t2006\t2/13/2006\tIndia in Pak...   NaN
2   Pakistan\tIndia\t2006\t2/19/2006\tIndia in Pak...   NaN
3
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., sep = '\t')?`

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Pandas - Read csv file with tab as delimter is not working as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250575/python-pandas-read-csv-file-with-tab-as-delimter-is-not-working-as-desired)

Comment: still issue i checked that link