# how can I split a dataframe with \t to columns

Tags: dataframe

After I read csv and I have a datafram like that

```
Year\tWhiteMale\tWhiteFemale\tBlackMale\tBlackFemale
0   1900\t46.6\t48.7\t32.5\t33.5
1   1950\t66.5\t72.2\t59.1\t62.9
2   1960\t67.4\t74.1\t61.1\t66.3
3   1970\t68.0\t75.6\t60.0\t68.3
4   1975\t69.5\t77.3\t62.4\t71.3
```

I want to split it to columns with headers and data

```
  Year WhiteMale WhiteFemal BlackMale BlackFemal 
0 1900 46.6      48.7        32.5      33.5     
1 1950 66.5     72.2        59.1      62.9 
2 1960  67.4    74.1        61.1      66.2        
3 1970  68.0    75.6        60.0      68.3
4 1975 69.5     77.3        62.4     71.1
```

many thanks

Comment: I found the anwser. thanks! df = pd.read_csv('life_expectancy.csv',sep='\t')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Pandas - Read csv file with tab as delimter is not working as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250575/python-pandas-read-csv-file-with-tab-as-delimter-is-not-working-as-desired)

Answer (score 0):

> I found the answer. thanks! `df = pd.read_csv('life_expectancy.csv',sep='\t')`
> Question answered by OP